# 'Computed field' controll and disableOutputTag="true" doesnt work?

Tags: xpages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XPages disableOutput tag issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700830/xpages-disableoutput-tag-issue)

I have a computed field control on my xpage that generates HTML (escape=false). As default the computed field generates span tag arround the content which causes some visual inconsistencies in IE. So I set the disableOutputTag="true" for this computed field but in this case, computed field doesnt generate anything. I have the repeat controll disableOutputTag="true" and it work fine, but can get it work for computed text. Is this some bug or my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above,  [XPages disableOutput tag issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700830/xpages-disableoutput-tag-issue) discuss the same issue and remains unresolved ...