# Prevent span tags from being generated for computed HTML fields?

Tags: xpages

I have a computed field on my page that is set for HTML.  The HTML generates but each computed field gets wrapped by a span tag.   Is there any way to avoid this?

Is my question related to this question?

['Computed field' controll and disableOutputTag="true" doesnt work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623143/computed-field-controll-and-disableoutputtag-true-doesnt-work?rq=1)

I need to use the disable tags property but there appears to be a bug?

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Yes, this question looks like a duplicates duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, remove the name of the computed field.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `id` attribute (if you are not using the ID for any operation like partial refresh) and set the `disableTheme` attribute to `true`. For e.g.

```
<xp:text escape="true" disableTheme="true">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Value"}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

This would generate only text value without `span` tags.